# Creating BigQuery Views in Terraform

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform

I have a bunch of tables in BQ that are based on a google_bigquery_table resource in Terraform. I need to create a view for one of these tables, however, I don't want to create another terraform resource to avoid code duplication. This is how my resource looks like right now:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "default" {


dataset_id = "${var.dataset_id}"
  table_id   = "${var.table_id}"

  time_partitioning {
    type = "DAY" //Hardcoded because this is the only supported value
    field = "${var.time_partitioning_field}"
  }

  view {
    query = "${var.query}"
    use_legacy_sql = "${var.use_legacy_sql}"
  }

  schema =   "${file(var.schema)}"
}
```

The relevant view variables are:

```
variable "query" {
  type = "string"
  default = ""
}

variable "use_legacy_sql" {
  type = "string"
  default = "false"
}
```

I set the query variable to an empty String because I don't want any of my other tables to have a view.

Finally, here's the table module containing a view:

```
module "myTable-editedView-bigquery-table"{
  source  = "./../../modules/google-bigquery-table"
  version = "0.1"
  schema = "${var.myTable_schema}"

  dataset_id   = "${module.myDataset-bigquery-dataset.dataset_id[0]}"
  table_id     = "${var.myTable_editedView_table_id}"

  query = <<SQL
      SELECT col1 ,  col2, col3, col4, col5
      FROM `myProject.myDataset.myTable`
      SQL

  time_partitioning_field = "${var.time_partitioning_field}"
  is_ready      = "${module.myDataset-bigquery-dataset.is_complete}"
  is_ready      = "${module.myTable-bigquery-table.is_complete}"
}
```

My other tables are similarly formatted except I didn't provide a query variable/value because I don't want them to have a view.

Planning appeared to have gone well, but terraform apply resulted in an error for every existing table claiming that a query is required for a view. I suppose it makes sense since I define a query variable for each table, but I figured that it would default to an empty String and not create a view. What approach should I take from here?

Comment: It's a simple fix. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need is a [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) in order to only add the `view` block when needed:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "default" {
  dataset_id = var.dataset_id
  table_id   = var.table_id
    
  time_partitioning {
    type = "DAY" //Hardcoded because this is the only supported value
    field = var.time_partitioning_field
  }
  
  dynamic "view" {
    for_each = var.query == null ? [] : [var.query]
    content {
      query = view.value
      use_legacy_sql = var.use_legacy_sql
    }
  }
    
  schema =   file(var.schema)
}

variable "query" {
  type = "string"
  default = null
}

variable "use_legacy_sql" {
  type = "string"
  default = "false"
}
```

Note that you also don't need to use `"${var.var_name}"` everywhere, this is the same as just `var.var_name`. I think this was not the case in earlier Terraform versions, though.