# Create BigQuery views through Terraform only for some tables

Tags: view, google-bigquery, terraform

I am trying to create views in BigQuery but I don't need a view for each of the underlying tables. I know there is already this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949356/creating-bigquery-views-in-terraform) that covers the topic but there is a subtlety in my case and I can't figure out how to cope with it.

It all comes down to the fact that, in my Terraform project, we constantly loop over variables. So if I add a loop in the dynamic view block as suggested in the hyperlink I gave, I get a loop inside a loop and things get messy:

> No more than 1 "view" blocks are allowed

In addition to that, I get another error when I make use of the **each.value["has_view"] == true** condition:

> The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The
> given expressions are string and tuple, respectively.

Which I don't understand because I don't get why Terraform is seeing strings.

So here is the code in my main.tf:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "table" {
  for_each            = var.bq_tables
  project             = each.value["project"]
  dataset_id          = each.value["dataset_id"]
  table_id            = each.value["table_id"]
  deletion_protection = false
  schema              = file("${path.module}/mySchemaPath/${each.value["table_id"]}.json")
  labels = {
    "env" = var.env
  }
}


resource "google_bigquery_table" "view" {
  for_each            = var.bq_tables
  project             = each.value["project"]
  dataset_id          = each.value["dataset_id"]
  table_id            = "v_${each.value["table_id"]}"
  deletion_protection = false
  dynamic "view" {
    for_each            = var.bq_tables_operational
    content {
      query           = each.value["has_view"] == true ? file("${path.module}/myViewPath/${each.value["table_id"]}.sql") : []
      use_legacy_sql  = false
    }
  }
  labels = {
    "env" = var.env
  }
  depends_on = [google_bigquery_table.table]
}
```

And my variables are as follows:

```
variable "env" {
  type = string
}

variable "bq_tables" {
  type = map(object({
    project    = string
    dataset_id = string
    table_id   = string
    has_view   = bool
  }))
  default = {}
}
```

How can I loop over my views and at the same time their underlying tables while keeping the possibility to bypass the view creation for some of those tables?

Comment: This is the first time I don't get any reaction on SO... Would my question be unsolvable? :(

Comment: Ofcourse not. A bq table can have 1 view, so no inner for_each needed.

If the bq table for_each needs to include all bq_tables with has_view and all bq_tables_operational. Consider using setproduct to create a combination of all keys and next filter the keys out that don't have a view e.g.

for_each = { for p in setproduct(keys(var.bq_tables), keys(var, bq_tables_operational) : "${p[0]}_${p[1]}" => { table = var.bq_tables[p[0]], operational = var.bq_table_op[p[1]] } if var.bq_tables[p[0]].has_view }